# Show that $p$ isn't a prime in $Q[\sqrt{-1}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working with Gaussian Integers.

Part 1: Suppose $p$ is a rational prime congruent to $1$ mod $4$. How do I show that $p$ isn't a prime in $Q[\sqrt{-1}]$

Part 2: Using part 1 I need to show that if $p$ is a rational prime congruent to $1$ mod $4$ then there are rational integers $a$ and $b$ for which $p = a^2 + b^2$(an exact equality not congruence)

**What I have done:**

I don't know if this helps, but using the fact that $Q[\sqrt{-1}]$ is a UFD. Also in the book it says that "for every odd rational prime p, there is an $x$ that solves $x^2 ≡ −1$ mod $p$ for all rational primes $p$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $4$"

I wasn't able to do anything for part 2, because I am still having trouble with part 1. Can someone help me here?

Comment: For this question, it's important that you have a clear definition of "prime".  Which definition are you using when trying to solve the problem?

Comment: Where you write $Q$ you likely mean $Z$.

Comment: I think it would help you tremendously to factorize the integers 2 to 20 in this domain. This might make these highly abstract concepts much more concrete for you. e.g., $10 = (1 - i)(1 + i)(2 - i)(2 + i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we already know that $-1$ is a quadratic residue of any (ordinary) prime $p$ congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. It follows that there exists an ordinary integer $a$ such that $a^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

So $p$ divides $a^2+1$, that is, $p$ divides $(a+i)(a-i)$. Suppose that $p$ was a prime in the Gaussian integers. Then since the Gaussian integers are a UFD, we would have $p$ divides $a+i$ or $p$ divides $a-i$. But $p$ plainly divides neither. So $p$ cannot be prime in the Gaussian integers.

We now deal with Part 2,  using results/ideas that are likely already familiar. By Part 1, $p$ is not prime in the Gaussian integers. Thus $p$ is reducible. So there exist ordinary integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $(a+bi)(c+di)=p$ and neither $a+bi$ nor $c+di$ is a unit.

Since $p$ has norm $p^2$, we must have that the norm of $a+bi$ and the norm of $c+di$ are each $p$. This says that $a^2+b^2=p$.

Comment: Does this prove part 2?

Comment: No, it just deals with part 1. Part 2 is not hard now, do you want an outline?

Comment: It looks more than an outline. So is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Some detail about the norm may require expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime number. The ideal $(p)= p\Bbb Z[i]$ is prime (splits) in $\Bbb Z[i]$ if and only if the quotient ring
$$
A_p=\Bbb Z[i]/(p)
$$
is (is not) a field. But since $\Bbb Z[i]\simeq\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$ we easily have
$$
A_p\simeq\Bbb F_p[X]/{(X^2+1)}
$$
where $\Bbb F_p$ denotes the field with $p$ elements. Thus
$$
\text{$p$ factorizes in $\Bbb Z[i]$}
\Leftrightarrow
\text{$X^2+1$ factorizes in $\Bbb F_p[X]$}
\Leftrightarrow
\text{$-1$ is a square in $\Bbb F_p$}.
$$
When $p$ is odd the latter condition is itself equivalent to $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}=1$ (Legendre symbol) and the latter holds if and only if $p\equiv1\bmod4$.

Comment: I'm looking for an elementary approack

Comment: @jordan "Elementary" is rather subjective. Are the concept of UFD and the fact that $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a UFD elementary? If yes, my answer is elementary as well, if no, read Fermat!